\Makefile.win recipe for target 'OpenMp.exe' failed
# Project: OpenMp
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = one.o
LINKOBJ  = one.o
LIBS     = -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc -fopenmp
INCS     = -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = OpenMp.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -fopenmp
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -fopenmp
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

one.o: one.cpp
    $(CC) -c one.cpp -o one.o $(CFLAGS)

this is the makefile generated after compiling the code
it is showing an error on line 25
please find attach error logs
D:\New folder\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      D:\New folder\Makefile.win  recipe for target 'OpenMp.exe' failed


You left out the actually useful error message generated by ld.

Also note that dev-c++ 5.11 is ancient. At least upgrade to the 6.x series.

i uploaded the compliation log

Change both instances of $(CC) to $(CPP) because the C compiler has no clue about C++.
